# What should i do when i have low MMR

Tags: league-of-legends

I was on Silver3 and got the promos for Silver2.

Now I'm on Silver2 but my MMR is very low for for that league.

[image: MMR]

What should i do?

I'm asking because yesterday i won a game and I only got 9LP's and i dont know how to check if I won nice MMR to compensate the low LP's

There's any way to check how much MMR i won after a game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really nothing you can do except for winning to improve your MMR. Also keep in mind that these 3rd party websites are sometimes inaccurate (although the fact that you gain +9LP shows that your MMR is indeed too low).

If you continue playing with a healthy winrate (50% or more) your MMR will go back to normal.

+9 LP usually means that you are about 100 MMR too low which normalizes after about 50 games with a high winrate.

As soon as you get +18 for a win your MMR is "normal". Everything below is a lower MMR and everything above is a higher MMR.

Comment: +1 using LP as an indicator is more accurate, but only if you solo-queue

Comment: so... theres any way to check my real MMR? Can i check how much MMR i won after a game? If yes, where?

Comment: you can't. MMR is hidden. all op.gg does using an own algorythm to calculate it.

Answer (score 4):

### Don't trust this value

You are not in a Elo-Hell

You can look at this site 3 hours later and it will give you totally different values.

Comment: In the image above i can read "Bem-vindo ao ELO hell" -> translated -> "Welcome to Elo hell". What is that?

Comment: @msm.oliveira If you have a new question, ask it with the [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @Studoku ok. i just asked here so people dont think that i m just asking silly questions to earn points

Comment: @msm.oliveira It's not a silly question and I'd assume you were asking it so you'd get the answer.

Comment: @msm.oliveira ignore it...don't google it...elo-hell does not exist.

Comment: @msm.oliveira That line is actually a joke from the site devs.  No matter what score is presently, you're always told you're in "Elo Hell".

"Elo Hell" is a term that is used when people feel like they're stuck with terrible teammates due to their Elo rating (one's rank points) pairs them up with people of similar points who are "terrible at the game" and basically force the player to get stuck at the same rating indefinitely.

Elo Hell as a concept has always been a myth, but it's a meme these days when people use the word.

Comment: @NBN-Alex that's not true. they only view that message, when your MMR is significantly lower acording to their algorythm

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you enter a promo series using OP.GG you will notice a MMR spike which will usually state you are below or considered in "ELO hell". When I was Silver I 91 LP my ELO was considered normal (1450) and when I started my GOLD promo series it said my average MMR for this league was ~1600 MMR.